# UITextField and Progress bar

Tags: ios

I have UITextField and Progress view. I want that user enter the value in text field and in that time of amount the progress view should be filled up to 100% with smooth animation  and % of process completion should be show in label

I have written this code for it, it shows smooth animation of filled progress view but not shows % process completion.

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblProgres;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField       *txtValue;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressBar;
- (IBAction)btnRestPressed:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Memory Managment Method

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Action Method

- (IBAction)btnRestPressed:(id)sender {

    [self.progressBar setProgress:0.0];
}

- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {

       float val1 = 1/[self.txtValue.text floatValue];

//    [self.progressBar setProgress:0];
    NSTimer *timer =  [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:val1 target:self selector:@selector(startedProgress:)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
    if(self.progressBar.progress != 1.0)
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];



  }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Custom Method

- (void) startedProgress:(NSTimer *)timer{

    float val1 =  1/[self.txtValue.text floatValue];


            [UIView animateWithDuration:1/val1 animations:^{
                float i=0;;
                                if(self.progressBar.progress >= 0.0) {

                               //     for(i = 1; i <= 100*10; i++) {
                                        [self.progressBar setProgress:[self.progressBar progress] + 1 /val1  animated:YES] ;


                                        NSLog(@"%f",self.progressBar.progress);
                               //    }
                                    if(self.progressBar.progress == 1.0) {

                                        [timer invalidate];

                                    }

                }

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
           }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Initalize Method

+ (ViewController *)viewController {
    ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];
    return view;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark - Lifecycle Method

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
self.lblProgres.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %",self.progressBar.progress*100];
```

After

```
 [self.progressBar setProgress:[self.progressBar progress] + 1 /val1  animated:YES] ;
```

Comment: Please add a plain-English explanation of how this solves the problem.